# What's the quickest way to get an OpenAPI spec for existing web service

Tags: api, rest, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a running web server that uses restful API as its backend, wondering what is the most effective way to get the OpenAPI spec with the full set of APIs

just exploring ideas

Comment: What language is your API coded in?

Comment: Do you have access to the API source code? (In case the solution is to add some library to it.) Or is it a third-party API?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the source code, but manually searching through each API and writing the OpenAPI specification from scratch would be a time-consuming and tedious task. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient and quicker way to generate the specification.

Answer (score 0):

There is an project on GitHub called har2openapi you can checkout as well.

https://github.com/dcarr178/har2openapi